# bevel join corner design android button shape

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, android-drawable

[How to design this on android drawable rounded corners are possible but this design have beveled corners.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14M4Q.png)

Comment: use [nine patch drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch)

Comment: in nine patch drawables I am still getting curved button shape.

Comment: whats your .9.png drawable like? post it here

Comment: [link](https://developer.android.com/images/ninepatch_examples.png)
This is how it will be looking like?

Answer (score -1):

[ShapeOfView Library can be used] (https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView)

Comment: Really overkill, when all you need is a background image.